# Uut of memory 4294967293 while fetching data from MS SQL [Through PHP ODBC]

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2012, odbc

I am trying to fetch data from MS SQL, its working good but after fetching some record the script get stopped and throws the following error,

**PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 6291456) (tried to allocate 4294967293 bytes)**

Can anyone help me on this? As i am fetching the records in loop only in which every loop fetches only 200 datas.

**Also the length of any fields in MS SQL don't have varchar(max), all are with something like 100, 200 only**

i am using `odbc_fetch_array` to fetch the data.

Comment: And you're probably building a large collection array of all the results, which takes a lot of memory.... process each result as you fetch it, don't try to store it all in PHP memory first

Comment: without having a look at your actual code, we can't really tell what part of the code causes the problem.

Comment: you may need to add configurations,count of records too

Comment: @MarkBaker i am storing only 200 data and again reset that array for next loop

Comment: @FranzGleichmann i am getting error in this line of code "while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($executeStatement)) {"

Comment: @TheGameiswar What configuration i need to do? Can you please tell clearly?

Comment: SQL Server configuration memory

Comment: @TheGameiswar didnt get you.. Can you please tell me what SQL Server Configuration do i need to do?

Comment: Since you are executing a tool or some program ,you may need to look at RAM on that place along with SQL server ram..select 
      (physical_memory_in_bytes/1024)/1024 AS physical_memory_in_mb 
from 
      sys.dm_os_sys_info
..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that not enough memory for php script.

1. You should collecting garbage every iteration (don`t collect all data from database in a variable during the loop).
2. Try increase php memory_limit

   ```
    echo ini_get("memory_limit");
    ini_set("memory_limit", "512M");
   ```
3. To be convinced that on the server free memory is enough. May be using atop, htop on linux.